# How to add new key value pair to a field which is defined as JSON in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have created a table with 3 fields:

```
id varchar(100) Primary key,
name varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
details json
```

I have inserted 1 value to the details as

```
{ 
"age" 10,
"class": "4th",
"sport": "TT"
}
```

now I wanted to add a new key-value to this details field.

> marks: 73

so final result should be:

```
{ 
"age" 10,
"class": "4th",
"sport": "TT",
"marks": 73
}
```

I have tried this query:

```
UPDATE studentable set details = details || '{"marks": 73"}' where id = 1
```

> GEtting ERROR: column details is of type json but expression is of
> type text.

I have tried removing ' from the '{"marks": 73"}' then it gives

> error: syntax error at or near "{"

Comment: change type of the field from json to jsonb. As far as i know most json operators defined on jsonb type

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb,*"  - you just found one reason this is recommended

Comment: There's already a typo here due to `73"` which is neither non-quoted nor quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you try to concatenate a json object with a text.
So you just have to cast your text as a json value  :

```
UPDATE studentable set details = details || '{"marks": 73"}' :: json where id = 1
```

Then, as already commented, you should use the jsonb type instead of json.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue while updating json column with value taken from some of the columns in the same table.
So, it can be helpful for someone you want to update the json the similar way.

```
UPDATE studentable SET details = COALESCE(details, '{}') || ('{"name":"' || COALESCE(name, 'Null-Value') || '"}') :: json where id = 1;
```

Note: I've use COALESCE to handle null value scenario for details and name column.

Idea is to create a string and then cast it to json.